# sort Find how many distinct values are among the certain column

Tags: sort, cut, wc, uniq

For example, this is the list.txt

```
Joe 3
Jack 1
Ulysses 6
Fox 2
Cassidy 1
Jones 6
Kevin 7
```

Then the output should be `5` because there are 5 different values in the 2rd column.

How should I finish this by only using `sort` `cut` `wc` `uniq`?

I have an idea, first use `sort -k2n` to sort the second column in increasing order and then use `uniq` to eliminate the second-column duplicated rows, and then the result would be like

```
Cassidy 1
Fox 2
Joe 3
Jones 6
Kevin 7
```

and then I use `cut -d ' ' -f2` to list all the numbers like `1 2 3 6 7`
and then I use `wc -d` to count the number of distinct values and this will return `5`.

What should I do in the `uniq` part to eliminate the duplicated rows with the same number?

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would start with `cut` since you only care about uniqueness in column 2:

```
cut -d' ' list.txt
```

results in:

```
1
2
1
3
6
7
6
```

Now you want unique values; uniq will do that, but only if it's sorted. If you're going to sort, go ahead and use sort's -u flag:

```
cut -d' ' -f2 list.txt | sort -u
```

Results in:

```
1
2
3
6
7
```

and now you can use `wc` to count the number of lines of output:

```
cut -d' ' -f2 list.txt | sort -u  | wc -l
```

which gives you:

```
5
```

Note that we're relying a specific format for the list.txt file -- no spaces in people's names!

Answer (score 2):

I would go with:

```
sort -k2,2 -u names | wc -l
5
```

Where `names` has this content:

```
cat names
Joe 3
Jack 1
Ulysses 6
Fox 2
Cassidy 1
Jones 6
Kevin 7
```

Comment: Clever combination of the key field with `-unique`!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are required to use `-sort -cut -wc -uniq`, then it seems that the required command line should be something like this:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f2 file.txt | sort -n | uniq | wc -l
5
```